# Java is slower than the browser in opening URL stream

Tags: java, network-programming

I am reading a url using

```
new URL(url).openStream();
```

and realized that it takes three times longer than what it takes for the browser according to fireBug. The openStream() method takes a little bit more than a second but the browser reads the whole thing in 300 ms. Can some one tell me how I can optimize it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Using native code.

Problem is that code in Java works not so fast, as browser created using webkit or native code.

Comment: I tested it in firefox but still I doubt if gets 3 times slower because of Java. Don't you think so?

Comment: @user650585 I was surprised too :) For example: in Android WebView (which uses webkit) works 3-4 times faster than pure Java.